# Multilevel mediation analysis (2-1-1-2 mediation) in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-model

I aim to perform a 2-1-1-2 mediation analysis with Trait A being the IV, Trait B being the DV (both on Level 2) and both State A and State B being two Level-1 mediators. I assume the Level-1-mediators to be correlated.

My data is experience sampling data that includes traits measured with multiple items and states measured with a single item each on multiple occasions per day over a week.

Do you have any advice on how to model such a mediation analysis in R (i.e, package recommendations, tutorials)? I would also be very happy about literature recommendations on this (I already know Bolger & Laurenceau, 2013). 
Unfortunately, I did not find anything helpful for more than one mediator and if the mediator is on Level-1 but IV and DV are on Level-2.

Answer (score 0):

R cannot estimate random slope effect. 
I'll suggest to run it in Mplus. But I feel Mplus is not that user-friendly and you have to deal with its environment.